# В огороде или на огороде?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вопрос, аналогичный "Во дворе — на дворе". Но интересует конкретно этот случай. Овощи растут в огороде или на огороде? И кто-то провел весь день, работаю на или в огороде?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это как Вы себе огород представляете - как саму  землю или как огороженный участок её.

Огород (первоначально) - огороженный участок земли под овощами. Овощи растут НА участке земли и В огороженном пространстве. Возможно и НА, и В.

Работаем НА грядках земли В огороженном пространстве - возможно и НА, и В.

Answer (score 2):

Я не вижу смысловой разницы. И **В** и **НА** тут означает и участок и его "внутренность".
Сравните: "во дворе" и "на дворе". Ничего, что предполагало бы принципиальную необходимость чего-то огороженного. Тут обычное изменение сочетаемости конкретного предлога с конкретным словом. Сравните еще: [был] на театре (до XIX века) и [был] в театре (позднее). Можно связывать причины такого изменения в разных трактовках "театра" (как зрелища и как здания), но смысл-то от этого не изменится. В обоих случаях понимается одно и то же действие. Аналогично, думаю, и с огородом.

Ещё показательнее "на деревню дедушке", коим крестьянский мальчик Ванька Жуков снабдил свое послание. А уж в крестьяснкой-то среде такие вещи чувствовали... 
Разница в смыслах проявляется в каких-то других случаях, так из общего значения в селе / на селе постепенно развилась дифференциация в конкретном ("нашем") селе и "в сельской местности". Но не похоже, что с огородом есть или могло быть что-то подобное.

Признаюсь, сначала пытался найти какое-то субъективное различие по линии "работать/находиться", но отверг даже эту мысль.

Answer (score 1):

В Нацкорпусе: **на огороде** ― 560 примеров, **в огороде** ― 740 примеров, счет почти равный. **Из этого делаем вывод, что падежные формы в большинстве случаев заменяют друг друга.** Работать в огороде (объемное огороженное пространство)  или на огороде (на грядках в огороде, плоское место)  ― это одно и то же.

Но в редких случаях **приходится выбирать нужную форму**, например:  **...**на огороде** лежал ослепляющий своей белизной иней. [Г. М. Марков. Строговы. Кн. 1 (1936-1948)]